# Using two or more optimize option with GCC command

Tags: linux, gcc, gcc4.7

I am trying to compile a opensource component from source code. I am compiling all C files in that component using `gcc` command.

When I pass options in order `-O2 -Os`, binary is in few KB's. But when I pass options in order `-Os -O2` binary size is large.

I do know that order matter in case of including sub-directories or Linking libraries in `gcc` command. 
Why order matters for optimization arguments of `gcc` command ?

I am using gcc version 4.9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's just using the last<sup>1</sup> option it sees.

---

<sup>1. From the man page: *If you use multiple -O options, with or without level numbers, the last such option is the one that is effective.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From the GCC [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html):

> If you use multiple `-O` options, with or without level numbers, the last such option is the one that is effective.

You can't combine `-O2` and `-Os` on the command line.

But here's the description of `-Os`:

> Optimize for size. **`-Os` enables all `-O2` optimizations that do not typically increase code size**.  It also performs further optimizations designed to reduce code size.

Looks like `-Os` is already doing what you want.